# exception: Access violation

Tags: c++, visual-c++

What's wrong with this code below and how to fix it.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename Func1, typename Func2>
class guard{
public:
    guard(Func1 first, Func2 last) : last(last){
        first();
    }
    ~guard(){
        last();
    }
private:
    Func2& last;
};

template<typename Func1, typename Func2>
guard<Func1, Func2> make_guard(Func1 first, Func2 last){
    return guard<Func1, Func2>(first, last);
}

void first(){
    cout << "first" << endl;
}

void last(){
    cout << "last" << endl;
}

int main(){
    {
        first(); // ok
        last(); // ok
        auto g = make_guard(first, last);
        first(); //exception: Access violation
        last(); //exception: Access violation
    }
    first(); // ok
    last(); // ok
    cin.get();
}
```

The function `first()` and `last()` can't be called before variable `g` expired. Compiled at VC++ 2012 and got the same problem both in debug and release mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `guard` keeps a *reference*, but it takes a *value*. The *reference* becomes invalid as soon as `guard`'s constructor end, as it refers to the `last` parameter taken by the constructor and not to the parameter passed to `make_guard`.

Once you access an invalid reference you have *undefined behavior*, and all bets are off.

Comment: Thank you. already fix it. But I still don't understand why call function `first()` and `last()` directly failed when variable `g` isn't expired.

Comment: Aren't `first` and `last` addresses of global functions? Why do they become invalid?

Comment: @user93353: `first` and `last` **are** addresses of global functions, but copying them gets you local pointers to such functions. It is the reference to the temporary copy of the pointer to that address that becomes invalid.

Comment: Ok - didn't notice that the private member `last` was a reference. Simple fix is to not make it a reference. `Func2 last`